# Website Won't Load without WWW Prefix - WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

We had this issue before with our old website, but only in certain browsers. We recently pushed our new website live and the issue now seems to be affecting all browsers. When you visit the website without the WWW prefix, you are taken to a "Under Construction" page that I'm told is a server error page of some sort.

Here is the domain:
www.mcfaddengavender.com

Here is my current .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Would it be possible to force all browsers to load the WWW prefix?

Answer (score 2):

DNS propagation could explain why it does not work. No, you should not need to force browsers to reload with www (which I just saw you did). You should use a CNAME record in your DNS to map your www subdomain on your main domain.

Comment: I have not modified the htaccess at all, a plugin could possibly be making changes to it. Which part of the rule could be causing the issue?

Comment: You have put a 301 redirect in place from http://mcfaddengavender.com to www.mcfaddengavender.com. Are you saying you didn't do it yourself? Anyway, your problem is a DNS problem. Is your new website on the same server as the old one? Same domain name? Did you change your DNS for the new website?

Comment: Oh sorry, I temporarily put one in place to see if that would fix this issue - which obviously it did not. The domain is the same as the old site, but as I mentioned, the old website had the same issue (just not on as many browsers). I'm going to take a look at the DNS records now.

Comment: Use `www.domainname.com. CNAME domainname.com.`

Comment: That DNS Record already seems to exist in the cPanel. There is also an A record with the name "mcfaddengavender.com" and the record is an IP address - is that correct? The domain also seems to contain a TXT record - could that cause an issue?

Comment: Where is this DNS? On the same server as the website is on? The A record is used when you point to another machine. So if your website is on another machine, yes, you need it, with the IP of the server on which your website is. But then it is on your website server that you actually also need the CNAME record. Except if you ISP is providing a simplified DNS zone management tool.

Comment: The domain is registered through GoDaddy but the website itself is hosted by HostGator. Since I have an A record, do I also need the CNAME record? Thanks for being patient with me - I'm far from a server/DNS person.

Comment: Ok fine, so you need the A record on GoDaddy and a CNAME record on HostGator (if you have a DNS zone management area on HostGator... do you?).

Comment: In my HostGator DNS zone editor, I see both an A record (which points to a domain) and a CNAME record (that points to mcfaddengavender.com with no WWW prefix). Once again, thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your .htaccess file looks fine and is normal.

You don't need anything in .htaccess to force or remove www with a Wordpress site. Add or delete the www prefix in Dashboard>>Settings>>General and save.

Comment: When I tried that, the website does not load at all. The only way to get the website functioning again was to FTP into the theme's function.php file and add the WWW prefix back to the URL.

Comment: That's strange that something in functions.php is impacting the URL. Update your question with that function; that's probably the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will solve the issue you're having, but to force a **www** in the domain name, you can add this **above** the `# BEGIN WordPress` line:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mcfaddengavender\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mcfaddengavender.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you! Nut unfortunately, no luck.

Answer (score -1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mcfaddengavender\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mcfaddengavender.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This proccess is working for me.