# Wordpress blank page issue without www & /

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain

I am developing a wordpress site.

When I am accessing the site without www, it is showing just a blank page for me. But if I give the address with www, it is opening properly.

```
mysite.com  (showing blank page)
www.mysite.com   (showing site properly)
```

Here one more issue is, for subpages if I dont give a '/' at the end of the URL it is showing blank page again. If I give '/' at the end it is showing properly.

```
www.mysite.com/page1  (blank page)
www.mysite.com/page1/  (showing the page)
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with WordPress system itself, but with the Apache configuration, most probably with `.htaccess` file.

Preceding the domain name with `www.` is just a popular choice. A website **can have** any valid fully qualified domain name. If you own the domain example.com, nothing at all prevents you from running a website called `superchickens.example.com`.

In practice, though, users expect two things, and if you don't provide them users will be frustrated and not find your site:

1. If your domain is `example.com`, then your website needs to respond when a user types just example.com in the address bar and presses Enter, because that is convenient.
2. Your website should also respond with the same content when a user types `www.example.com`, because the `www.` prefix is very common and many users will assume they must provide it.

   So how do you do this? If you are **paying for service from a web hosting company**, and `www.example.com` works but `example.com` doesn't, then your hosting company **needs to fix** that for you right away. **Contact technical support** and let them know you will be switching hosting companies if they don't fix it promptly. There is no valid reason why they can't make both names work for you. It is a very simple change to the web server's configuration and they ought to be doing it automatically for every new customer anyway.

However, if you are running the web server **yourself** -- possibly because you run a web hosting company -- here are the steps you need to follow to do the job:

1. Adjust the DNS settings for example.com. Make sure you have address records (type A records) for both example.com and `www.example.com`, with the same IP address. This is not hard to do at all with both Windows and Linux DNS servers.
2. If you are using virtual hosting to provide many websites on a single IP address, you will also need to tell your web server about the alternative name for the site. In your web server's configuration, add example.com as an alias for www.example.com. In an Apache server `httpd.conf` file, this typically looks like:

   `<VirtualHost *>
      DocumentRoot /home/www/web
      ServerName www.example.com
      ServerAlias example.com
    </VirtualHost>`

Only the `ServerAlias` directive is new. the rest is shown to provide context. Your Apache `VirtualHost` configuration may not be identical.

After the configuration file is edited the Apache web server must be signaled to reload its configuration. On a typical Unix system this can be done with the following command:

`service httpd reload`

Also you may read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809821/website-wont-load-without-www-prefix-wordpress) Stackoverflow question.